# error with shell script looping over sub-directories in directory

Tags: linux

I am trying to loop through all the sub-directories in a directory and to copy the pathname of all files containing the word "event" into a new listfile. But, for some reason my code only looks at the last sub-directory...any ideas?

```
for dir in */

do

echo "$dir"

ls -l $dir* | grep events > FullSkim.list

done
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change `>` to `>>`.

- `>`(Redirecting Output): If the file does not exist it is created; if it does exist it is truncated to zero size.
- `>>`(Appending Redirected Output): If the file does not exist it is created; if it does exist it is opened for appending.

Answer (score 0):

you could instead use

```
find . | grep "events" > file
```